# Detect only elements in viewport jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, viewport

I  have the following:

```
    <div id="btnL">Left</div>
    <div id="btnR">Right</div>

    <table id="tab1">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Item</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Descript</td>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                    </tr>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <tr>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                            <td>Entry</td>
                    </tr>

            </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
            $("#btnR").click(function(e) {
                    $("#tab1 thead tr td:nth-child(n+2).css("display","table-cell");
                    $("#tab1 thead tr td:nth-child(-n+1).css("display","none");
            });
            $("#btnL").click(function(e) {
                    $("#tab1 thead tr td:nth-child(n+2).css("display","none");
                    $("#tab1 thead tr td:nth-child(-n+1).css("display","table-cell");
            });
    </script>
```

The code works as expected, hiding and showing the last element.  The issue is there are 20,000 rows in the table and rendering is very slow.  I would like to only affect elements in the viewport (+- a few) and as the user scrolls down change the others as opposed to change them all at once.

Comment: Can you also paste the javascript code :D

Comment: That is the javascript code that runs very slowly.

Comment: Sorry, now I saw it at the bottom

Comment: Why are you rendering 20,000 rows at once?

Comment: I agree, there should be paging in the first place

Comment: Sorry but I'm failing to see how this works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to hide a particular column. During creation of table attach a class to each td of that column (let's say class is called `specialTD`).

Make entry in your css like this:

> table.hideCol .specialTD { display: none; }

Now whenever you need to hide/show the column, just add/remove the class on the table.

---

On a side note, your child selector seems incorrect to me.

> -n + 1 will only mean first td.
>    n + 2 will mean every td starting from second.

refer http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/